# C#: Auto text highlight in RichText

Tags: c#

I am extremely very new to C#, just wrote some calculator, text editors and DB client in the school almost 10 years ago :) Not I am trying to make a tool for myself and my colleagues to view traces and logs in easier way. All we know Notepad++, we used daily for text highlighting, styling, but the thing is that these highlights get lost after you close Notepad++.
So my goal now is to make the same text editor but so it will be able to save your work.Currently I am working on the feature so when I am selecting some text, it will search for the same on whole document and highlight it, for example with red background. I added this one:

```
 private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int startIndex = 0;

            while (startIndex<richTextBox1.TextLength)
            {
                int wordStartIndex = richTextBox1.Find(richTextBox1.SelectedText, startIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                if (wordStartIndex != -1)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = wordStartIndex;
                    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
                    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                    break;
                startIndex += wordStartIndex + richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
            }


        }
```

But it gives me "StackOverFlow" as I have a loop here. Can you please assist me with it?
I think I need to run 2 searches to avoid loop - one before selection index, one after. Or maybe there is easier option?

Thank you all, guys!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an infinite loop because you're in an event that checks for a selection change, and then in that event, you're changing the selection, which causes an event, where you change the selection, which causes an event...

If you want to avoid this you'll need a class level variable like

```
bool inSelectionChangeEvent;
```

and then change your code to:

```
 private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (!inSelectionChangeEvent){
    inSelectionChangeEvent = true;
   }
   else{
    return;
   }
...
```

Also, you're writing your OWN text editor? Err, there *may* be a simpler solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the selection length. Right here:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
```

It does no good to set something equal to itself and I'm guessing this was an accident. When the SelectionLength is 0, `startIndex` never increases (anything + 0 is anything).

The first thing I'd do is check if `richTextBox1.SelectionLength < 1` and if it is, just return from the method without doing anything.

This code snippet from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62c43124-a2d4-47f5-b30e-2da1ad38ffad/highlight-multiple-found-word-in-rtb-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) should help you accomplish what you're doing:

```
string wordToFind = "melp";
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf( wordToFind );
while( index != -1 )
{
    richTextBox1.Select( index, wordToFind.Length );
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

    index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf( wordToFind, index + wordToFind.Length );
}
```